# Is there a control for .NET that is similar to the completion graph in uTorrent?

Tags: c#, controls

For reference, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YSLQ.png). It's similar to a progressbar except instead of the usual 0%-XX% filled in, this can have any arbitrary range filled in. I tried searching but did not know how to describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you likely won't find a generic control out there to do that.

However, the concept is simple, you could roll your own fairly easily using GDI+